# A Forked Path in the Forest

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, situation

You, a young adventurer, are travelling through the forest. Suddenly, your path splits in 2. You have no map or compass - well, you do but your compass is broken. You know you have to keep travelling North, so how can you tell which direction to go in? You do not have much time, you must leave now!

Where are you going to go?!

Comment: I navigated munich by using the position of the sun once (needed to go south). But I guess I can't see the sun through the treetops/the sun is directly above?

Comment: It isn't clear to me how this is a puzzle.

Comment: Seems very similar to  [the lighthouse keeper](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/lighthouse-keeper-stuck-the-bath) -- Q: OMG how to solve problem? A: there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *have to* keep travelling North, you’re already going North and you can’t take a path that’s not North, so pick the one straight ahead.

Comment: I have a feeling that "have to" in this case doesn't imply a physical impossibility.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i have a solution : don't care about paths, just continue straight forward

Answer (score 1):

Since moss grows on the north side of a tree, it will point the way.

Comment: ... as famously stated by Arya Stark in A Song of Ice and Fire.

Comment: No it doesn't. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzQw00SSOQQ

Comment: Whether the moss grows on a certain side of trees and which side that is depends on the prevailing wind.

Comment: On most of the trees is no moss. So this theoretical rule is useless in real world.